# Axios doesn't send headers from request interceptors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

On my front-end I have this `Axios` code:

```js
import axios from "axios";
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'

const apiUrl = process.server ? `${process.env.FRONT}api/` : '/api/';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiUrl,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})

api.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  if (token) {
    config.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
  }
  return config;
}, function (error) {
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

export const login = async (payload) => {
  const { data } = await api.post(`login`, payload)
  return data
}
```

What this code does is just set some headers with token. Then, this request goes to front-end server:

```js
router.post(`/login`, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await api.post('/login', req.body)
    res.json(data.data)
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(e.response.status).json(e.response.data)
  }
})
```

If you do `console.log(req.headers)` here, it's gonna be okay, headers will look like this:

```
req.headers {
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  host: 'localhost:8010',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '898',
  authorization: 'Bearer ...token...',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36',
...
}
```

And here is the problem, after that, when request goes to back end, it's captured by middleware `auth`:

`router.post('/login', auth, accountController.login)`

This is how this middleware looks like:

```js
import * as jwtService from './../services/jwtService';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { CommonResponse } from "../responses/response";

export default async (req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => {
  try {
    if (req.headers.authorization) {
      const user = await jwtService.getUser(req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1])
      if (user) next();
      else return CommonResponse.common.unauthorized({ res })
    } else {
      return CommonResponse.common.unauthorized({ res })
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return CommonResponse.common.unauthorized({res});
  }
}
```

And here is the problem, if you do `console.log(req.headers)` here you'll see, this:

```
{
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'user-agent': 'axios/0.26.0',
  'content-length': '898',
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'close'
}
```

What happened to my headers?

By the way, if on front end server you do this:

`const data = await api.post('/login', req.body, {headers: req.headers})`

This is going to work, but still, what happened? Is this how interceptors should work?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly but, you do have 2 servers and both of them listen to the `/login` route. And you have 1 `front-end` that sends a request using `api.post` to the first (front-end) server you have.

And that request is listened with `router.post(..` and it's being sent to backend-server with `api.post(`. I don't understand this `frontend-server` thing but I don't expect it to have access to `localStorage`. Therefore `localStorage.get` will not work in my opinion. Because `localStorage` is a browser aspect. Correct me if I'm missing or misunderstanding anything.

Comment: ++ Because of this, you have to parse `token` from the incoming request headers, not with the same exact interceptor (due to it's possible fail caused by `localStorage.get`). And I think this is why `const data = await api.post('/login', req.body, {headers: req.headers})` this code works. Because it takes the headers from the `req.headers` and it's not running `localStorage.get`.

Comment: @archon I'd like to correct you, actually, front-end server, as you called it, has access to `localStorage`, if before that `const { data } = await api.post(`login`, payload)` you do `console.log(req.headers)`, you will see there `Bearer *token*`, but this front-end header doesn't to back-end server, here is the problem.

Comment: I still might be misunderstanding but what I'm saying is `console.log(req.headers)` will work because you are logging the `req.headers`, what I've tried telling is that `window.localStorage.get` will not work because there shouldn't be any `window` if this is running on Node. Because `localStorage` is actually within `window` object and we can't use it with `node`. It's browser specific. So, your front-end code can have access to `localStorage` and interceptors will work fine and it will pass the data correctly to the server (req.headers), however the same interceptor won't work on server.

Comment: I agree with you, you are right, but this flow looks like this - I put headers on front-end (where I have access to `localStorage`, you can see this in code), and then, just send request body and **headers** to back-end.

Comment: Look, first `console.log` is log from front-end, but the second `console.log(req.headers)` is log from back-end, look how different they are.

Comment: Can you try logging the error on the interceptor callback that is on frontend-server? @dokichan

Comment: I still think that this is the issue. And it's normal that your first `console.log(req.headers)` is fine because you're passing it from the client which has the HTML webpage that runs on the browser and has access to `localStorage` so it can use the interceptor without an issue and pass the data in the headers. But if you use the same `api` module which has this particular interceptor on your `frontend-server`, it'll fail. Because it doesn't run on a browser. It doesn't have access to any browser functionalities. And `localStorage.get` is probably throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the reason behind it is that you're assigning to `request.headers.common`.
It works for me when I assign to `req.headers`

```
api.interceptors.request.use(
   (req) => { // I'm using req instead of config just for clarity
      req.headers['Authorization'] = `token ${token}`
      return req;
   },
   (err) => {
      return Promise.reject(err);
   }
);
```

In your server side, change `req.headers.authorization` to `req.headers.Authorization`

```
import * as jwtService from './../services/jwtService';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { CommonResponse } from "../responses/response";

export default async (req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => {
  try {
    if (req.headers.Authorization) {
      const user = await jwtService.getUser(req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1])
      if (user) next();
      else return CommonResponse.common.unauthorized({ res })
    } else {
      return CommonResponse.common.unauthorized({ res })
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return CommonResponse.common.unauthorized({res});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code of interceptors as follows:

```
api.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
 const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
 if (token) {
   config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
 }
 return config;
}, function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

And in middleware you should use Authorization instead of authorization like:

```
import * as jwtService from './../services/jwtService';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { CommonResponse } from "../responses/response";

export default async (req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => {
  try {
    if (req.headers.Authorization) { // correct this line
      const user = await jwtService.getUser(req.headers.Authorization.split(' ')[1]) // correct this line
      if (user) next();
      else return CommonResponse.common.unauthorized({ res })
    } else {
      return CommonResponse.common.unauthorized({ res })
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return CommonResponse.common.unauthorized({res});
  }
 }
```

And make sure that you have token in localStorage too and provide feedback if still facing issue.

Comment: No, doesn't work, I still get default headers: `{
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'user-agent': 'axios/0.26.0',
  'content-length': '898',
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'close'
}`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no issue with code.

Try this demo and it works fine.
https://github.com/indolent-developer/axiosDemo

Most probably you are having issue with localstorage. Generally I like to avoid if without else. Can you can some console logs and see it is working fine.